# Printing Image from JLabel in java

Tags: java, swing, printing

I'm writing a code which generate barcode in Image then display this image in label in my form then I want to print this barcode so I wrote this code

```
Icon icon = lbl.getIcon();
BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(icon.getIconWidth(), icon.getIconHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics graphic = bi.createGraphics();
try {
    lbl.printAll(graphic);
    JOptionPane.showmessage(null, "success");
    g.dispose();
} catch(Exception ex) {
    JOptionPane.showmessage(null, "Error While Printing : " + ex.getMessage());
}
```

but I can't try it because I don't have printer, so this code will run correctly or any updates ?

Comment: You know you can print to a virtual printer in order to generate an image of what the printed page would look like, right? Try searching "virtual printer" for your OS.

Comment: *"print this barcode"* Always read the Java Docs for the methods being used!